# commandline with tex modifier not striping tabular config

Tags: bash, aspell

See in the following example that the `rl` string from the configuration of the `tabular` command is being parsed as text and passed into the spell checking feature of the `aspell` program. Where it's being outputted as an incorrect spelling. Which it is. But I didn't expect it would be parsed as text and checked at all.

```
# aspell -d en_GB -t list --encoding utf-8 -c < test.tex
rl
asdfa
sfasdf
# cat test.tex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{rl}
    asdfa & sfasdf\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Why is this happening, or is there anyway to correct it? I've tried multiple language files and different options. Along with ways of passing the file to the program.

edit (more tries):

```
# aspell -d en_GB -t list --encoding utf-8 -c --add-tex-command tabular p < test.tex
Unhandled Error: add-tex-command: The value "" is not a string of 'o','O','p',or 'P' and is thus invalid for the key "tabular".

# aspell -d en_GB -t list --encoding utf-8 -x --add-tex-command "tabular p" < test.tex
rl
asdfa
sfasdf
```

Answer (score 0):

This works but i'm not sure its the best option.

```
# aspell -d en_GB -t list --encoding utf-8 -x --add-tex-command "begin pp" < test.tex
asdfa
sfasdf
```